# Наскільки правильно писати "звільнилася вакансія"?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми, словосполучення

Словосполучення "вільна вакансія" вважається плеоназмом (надлишком), оскільки "вакансія" - вільна, незайнята посада. Тоді вона і "звільнитися" не може, так? Якщо бажано використати саме "вакансія", а не "посада", як краще сформулювати?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**З'явилася вакансія**, або будь-яке словосполучення, яке пасує до "вільна посада".

ВАКА́НСІЯ, ї, жін. Вільна посада в штаті установи. Ти накажи всім, кому можна, щоб стежили і не пропускали вакансії (Михайло Коцюбинський, III, 1956, 175); А недавно побачив у газеті оголошення, конкурсу на заміщення вакансії доцента в рідному університеті (Микола Руденко, Остання шабля, 1959, 38).

[СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vakansija)

Answer (score 3):

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/inshe/vakansiya)
[image]

Сайт [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%96%D1%8F/) радить

> **Вільна вакансія** — тавтологія, виправте: **вакансія.**

[СУМ-20](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=6444&page=236)

> ***ВАКА́НСІЯ***, ї, ж. 1. Вільна посада в штаті установи, закладу.